# Why query for indexed fields is indexOnly = false

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, nosql

I have collection users with default index _id.

I make this query:

```
db.users.find({ }, { "_id" : 1 }).limit(50);
```

Or this query:

```
db.users.find({ "_id" : NumberLong("382748936301357196") }, { "_id" : 1 }).limit(50);
```

I expect that these queries look only to index, because I don't wanna return any other fields than _id. But *explain* is saying that this query is not indexOnly. Why?

[image: Explain dotazu]

Comment: you are not actually querying/filtering for anything. You are asking for all documents.  Add something in the filter which queries by _id.  Or add a sort by _id.

Comment: Ok, I added find by id, but it's still indexOnly=false

Comment: works fine for me - what version are you on? {
 "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
 "isMultiKey" : false,
 "n" : 1,
 "nscannedObjects" : 0,
 "nscanned" : 1,
 "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
 "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
 "scanAndOrder" : false,
 "indexOnly" : true,
 "nYields" : 0,
 "nChunkSkips" : 0,
 "millis" : 0,
 "indexBounds" : {
  "_id" : [
   [
    ObjectId("516f00f6bfd3e39f184cfdc8"),
    ObjectId("516f00f6bfd3e39f184cfdc8")
   ]
  ]
 },

Comment: show your explain() output please?

Comment: I added explain for the query.

Comment: Interestingly, I just tried the same thing that @312k1t is experiencing and also see `indexOnly : false` for an `_id` only query (v 2.4.1).

Comment: are you running this in mongo shell?

Comment: could you include the record that's being returned when you run it with {_id:...} filter included?

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this behavior is if I don't have an index on _id on the collection (in fact only when the collection itself doesn't exist).  Could you post db.users.getIndexes() - you are getting back correct results of the query?